# How can I debug a project in IntelliJ and provide a context xml file?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, classloader, jetty-9

I have written a subclass of Jetty's WebAppClassLoader. I wrote a context XML file to configure the web app context with my classloader, enabled the ext module, and added my classloaders to $JETTY_BASE/lib/ext. This all works when I run my program outside of IntelliJ.

What I need to do though is run my program within IntelliJ. I have it working with the Jetty maven plugin, but this is not ideal because it forces the maven build to run each time I want to start the program which is quite slow.

As far as I can tell the only thing preventing this from working is that I can see no way to tell Jetty about my context XML file when I run it through the IntelliJ Jetty Run/Debug configuration.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Try adding deployment descriptor here: https://i.imgur.com/4J3Uc2q.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, it's a good idea but I already tried jetty-web.xml. The issue is that jetty-web.xml is processed too late, after the classloader is fixed.

Comment: Is using a junit test (instead of the Jetty IntelliJ Plugin) and option for you?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Maybe, it depends on how much it slows down the build.